# Using OR in CodeIgniter Active Record's Delete Method

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I need to be able to convert the following to Ci's active record delete method but I don't know how to use the OR in the delete statement. Could you please tell me how I'd do this correctly?

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM friend WHERE userid_friends = '{$userid}' AND friendId_friends = '{$targetedUserId}' OR userid_friends = '{$targetedUserId}' AND friendId_friends = '{$userid}' ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your trying this:

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM friend WHERE 
   ( userid_friends = '{$userid}' AND friendId_friends = '{$targetedUserId}')  OR 
   ( userid_friends = '{$targetedUserId}' AND friendId_friends = '{$userid}')  ");
```

(note the added parentheses for the two AND clauses)

But actually your not using CI's "DELETE" method just a query.

Using active record delete would be something like:

```
$this->db->where("userid_friends = '{$userid}' AND friendId_friends = '{$targetedUserId}'");
$this->db->or_where("userid_friends = '{$targetedUserId}' AND friendId_friends = '{$userid}'");
$this->db->delete('friend');
```

For debugging of complex queries I recommend you to use

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

As it shows you exactly how the final query was rendered by the Active record methods.